# How to install Flash player in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I have install Ubuntu 10 but you tube is not running on the firefox. I have downloaded flash player from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

A "install_flash_player_10_linux.tar.gz" file download in the downloads folder

Now i extract it

and i have found a file libflashplayer.so

now i try again and again but i can't able to install it

Please help me...

Comment: Might be worth asking on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, just install the package `flashplugin-installer` if you have the `multiverse`repository enabled.

Answer (score 1):

After extracting the libflashplayer.so file place it under the ${HOME_PATH}/.mozilla/plugins. Then restart firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve flash player installation in Ubuntu

I just open the terminal and type the following code and flash player get install

```
cd Downloads

tar -xzvf install_flash_player_10_linux.tar.gz libflashplayer.so

sudo mv -f libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/
```